# Why does same origin policy prevent accessing current folder and subfolders in file:// URLs?

Tags: html, security, web

I tried to think of an explanation or security risk that justifies the inconvenience of the status quo but couldn't see any succint reason why that is.

Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

To prevent a malicious HTML page in `C:\` from reading your entire hard drive.